# Cordova Android Build Failure

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to get the basic Cordova v5.0 Android v4.0 project to build on Mac OS X Yosemite, but keep getting this error.  Note: The same process builds fine on Cordova v4.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled the Android SDK, Cordova, and even Gradle (but I don't think I need it).  I've checked that my Path variable contains the correct paths to /tools and /platform_tools.  But when I do the 'cordova build' or 'cordova build android' I always get the same error:

> Could not create an instance of type
>   org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle_Decorated.

Further down it says:

> You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project

What am I missing?

Here's the full text of what I'm doing:

```
my_acct$cordova create build_test com.example.build_test "BuildTest"
Creating a new cordova project.
my_acct$cd build_test
my_acct$cordova platform add android
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    Package: com.example.build_test
    Name: BuildTest
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-22
Copying template files...
Android project created with cordova-android@4.0.0
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" in config.xml. Installing to the project
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1" via npm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-plugin-whitelist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-plugin-whitelist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-plugin-whitelist
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android
my_acct$cordova build
Running command: /Users/my_acct/Documents/Development/work/build_test/platforms/android/cordova/build 
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/my_acct/Documents/Development/android-sdk-macosx/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Running: /Users/my_acct/Documents/Development/work/build_test/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/my_acct/Documents/Development/work/build_test/platforms/android/build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle_Decorated.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

/Users/my_acct/Documents/Development/work/build_test/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: /Users/my_acct/Documents/Development/work/build_test/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/my_acct/Documents/Development/work/build_test/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/my_acct/Documents/Development/work/build_test/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Users/my_acct/Documents/Development/work/build_test/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/my_acct/.node/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

If I change to use java 1.7 or 1.8, the error changes to:

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
> > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+.
> >          Required by:
> >              :android:unspecified
> >     org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V

Here's the full results for using java 1.7 or 1.8:

```
my_acct$cordova build
Running command: /Users/my_acct/Documents/Development/work/build_test/platforms/android/cordova/build 
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/my_acct/Documents/Development/android-sdk-macosx/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
Running: /Users/my_acct/Documents/Development/work/build_test/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/my_acct/Documents/Development/work/build_test/platforms/android/build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.859 secs

/Users/my_acct/Documents/Development/work/build_test/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: /Users/my_acct/Documents/Development/work/build_test/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/my_acct/Documents/Development/work/build_test/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/my_acct/Documents/Development/work/build_test/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Users/my_acct/Documents/Development/work/build_test/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/my_acct/.node/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I found old, conflicting .jar files in ~/Library/Java/Extensions. Blew away the entire ~/Library/Java directory.  Cordova (and Android Studio) runs great now.

Answer (score 0):

The other way how this problem can be resolved is by changing the repository from

```
mavenCentral()
```

to

```
maven{
   url 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2'
}
```

in both *platforms/android/build.gradle* and *platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle*